# What are some simple methods to add diagnostic hooks into my Java backend code?

Tags: java, server, alert, backend, diagnostics

I'm looking for some simple methods to add some hooks into my Java backend code, like some counters or any other kind of value. These values should be easily accessible via an URL or API for monitoring or health-check. Also some tools to trigger an alert based on an unwanted condition that has arised in the server?

Comment: Erm ... there is no magic.  Though I guess you might consider using JMX to make the information available.

Comment: Reads like logging to me.

Comment: For the "Also ..." part.  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Based on my and Gilbert's comments.)

First of all, there is no magic bullet solution.  The actual work of gathering statistics, status values and the detection of "unwanted conditions" (or anomalous events) is down to the application code.

However, there some standard approaches to getting hold of this kind of information from a running application.

- Instead of exposing the stats and status info via HTTP(s), you could use [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/overview/intro.html) to expose is, and use off-the-shelf JMX console softeare to access it.
- The "unwanted conditions" / anomalous events requirement could be handled by using an off-the-shelf logging library.  You then use an off-the-shelf external monitoring tool / system to scan for events and generate notifications.

Is it worth the effort?  Depends on the nature of the server.  (And on how much effort you can avoid by using monitoring infrastructure paid for or run by someone else.)